# How do I assign Roles to Admin and other users of a website facilities/pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Good morning house, please am trying to assign roles to Admin to have access to all my supermarket pages/facilities while Manager and Employees will have limited access to some pages. These are my RoleController and UserController with other codes. It has created the Roles in the Database but everyone that logs in still have access to all the pages. How do I enforce this restriction please

//This is my StartUp class////

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Supermarket.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Supermarket.Startup))]
namespace Supermarket
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            createRolesandUsers();
        }

        // In this method we will create default User roles and Admin user for login   
        private void createRolesandUsers()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));





        // In Startup I am creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User    


    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
            {

                // first we create Admin role   
                var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Admin";
                roleManager.Create(role);

                //Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website                  

                var user = new ApplicationUser();
                user.UserName = "shanu";
                user.Email = "jobabs2013@gmail.com";       

                string userPWD = "babs4greatness";                

                var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

                //Add default User to Role Admin   
                if (chkUser.Succeeded)
                {
                    var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");

                }
            }

            // creating Manager role    
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Manager"))
            {
                var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Manager";
                roleManager.Create(role);

            }

            // creating Employee role    
            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Employee"))
            {
                var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
                role.Name = "Employee";
                roleManager.Create(role);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

//I have successfully done the Model and the View which worked fine///

/*This is my AccountContrller.cs class below foe Register GET AND POST*/

```
  // GET: /Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin"))
                                            .ToList(), "Name", "Name");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Account/Register   
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                    // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771   
                    // Send an email with this link   
                    // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);   
                    // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);   
                    // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");   
                    //Assign Role to user Here      
                    await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.UserRoles);
                    //Ends Here    
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
                }
                ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.Where(u => !u.Name.Contains("Admin"))
                                          .ToList(), "Name", "Name");
                AddErrors(result);
            }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form   
    return View(model);
}
```

//My UserController class///

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Supermarket.Models;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Supermarket.Controllers
{
    public class userController : Controller
    {
        // GET: user
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var user = User.Identity;
                ViewBag.Name = user.Name;

                ViewBag.displayMenu = "No";

                if (isAdminUser())
                {
                    ViewBag.displayMenu = "Yes";
                }
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Name = "Not Logged IN";
            }
            return View();
        }

        public Boolean isAdminUser()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var user = User.Identity;
                ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
                var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
                if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

//My RoleController class//

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Supermarket.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Supermarket.Controllers
{
    public class RoleController : Controller
    {
         ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();          // @todo
        // GET: Role
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                if (!isAdminUser())
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            var Roles = context.Roles.ToList();
            return View(Roles);

        }

        public Boolean isAdminUser()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var user = User.Identity;
                ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));
                var s = UserManager.GetRoles(user.GetUserId());
                if (s[0].ToString() == "Admin")
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All I did was to add [Authorizes(Roles="Admin")] OR Authorizes(Roles="Manager")] like this below in the Controller and View class

```
**[Authorizes(Roles="Admin, Manager")]**
namespace Supermarket.Controllers
{
    public class userController : Controller
    {
        // GET: user
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var user = User.Identity;
                ViewBag.Name = user.Name;

                ViewBag.displayMenu = "No";

                if (isAdminUser())
                {
                    ViewBag.displayMenu = "Yes";
                }
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Name = "Not Logged IN";
            }
            return View();
        }
```